# Dynamic import of an instance in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, vue-component, es6-promise

How can you create a dynamic import of an instance in vue using a parameter?

I would like to dynamically import the language into flatpickr-vue.

```js
import { de } from 'flatpickr/dist/l10n/de.js';
```

how do I bring the "locale" parameter into the import path dynamically?

```js
<akaunting-date
...
      :config="{
            ...
            locale: '{{ language()->getShortCode() }}',
        }"
...
></akaunting-date>
```

[Link to original code](https://github.com/akaunting/akaunting/blob/master/resources/views/partials/form/date_group.blade.php)

```js
<template>
    <base-input :label="title"
        :name="name"
        :class="[
            {'readonly': readonly},
            {'disabled': disabled},
            formClasses
        ]"
        :footer-error="formError"
        :prependIcon="icon"
        :readonly="readonly"
        :disabled="disabled"
        >
        <flat-picker slot-scope="{focus, blur}"
            @on-open="focus"
            @on-close="blur"
            :config="config"
            class="form-control datepicker"
            v-model="real_model"
            @input="change"
            :readonly="readonly"
            :disabled="disabled">
        </flat-picker>
    </base-input>
</template>

<script>
import flatPicker from "vue-flatpickr-component";
import "flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css";
import { de } from 'flatpickr/dist/l10n/de.js';

export default {
    name: 'akaunting-date',

    components: {
        flatPicker
    },

    props: {
        title: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            description: "Modal header title"
        },
        placeholder: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            description: "Modal header title"
        },
        readonly: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
            description: "Input readonly status"
        },
        disabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
            description: "Input disabled status"
        },
        formClasses: null,
        formError: null,
        name: null,
        value: {
            default: null,
            description: "Input value defalut"
        },
        model: {
            default: null,
            description: "Input model defalut"
        },
        config: null,
        icon: {
            type: String,
            description: "Prepend icon (left)"
        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            real_model: this.model
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.real_model = this.value;

        if (this.model) {
            this.real_model = this.model;
        }

        this.$emit('interface', this.real_model);
    },

    methods: {
        change() {
            this.$emit('interface', this.real_model);
            
            this.$emit('change', this.real_model);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

[Link to original code](https://github.com/akaunting/akaunting/blob/master/resources/assets/js/components/AkauntingDate.vue)

i think i'm on the right track ...

```js
    computed: {
            config() {
                return {                
                    locale: require('flatpickr/dist/l10n/' + this.locale + '.js').default.en,
                }
            }
        },
```

now I would have to change the ".en" in .default dynamically. is that possible?

is not yet completely dynamic and there is still the following error message, which I do not understand

```
[Vue warn]: The computed property "config" is already defined as a prop.
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `import * as locale from \`flatpickr/dist/l10n/${countryCode}.js\`;`

Comment: Have a look [here](https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports) for **dynamic imports** in the form of `let {hi, bye} = await import('./say.js');` , more [here](https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import)

Comment: `import * as locale from 'flatpickr/dist/l10n/${countryCode}.js'; `
i tried it, unfortunately without success!

Comment: `let {hi, bye} = await import('./say.js');` I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Because the module you want is not known at runtime, you will have to import it asynchronously, else your script will have to wait for the file to be fetched and parsed..

If you don't want to use the `promise.then()` route, then you can opt for this:

```js
// do something with the 'locale module' once it is available
function sayHelloTo(locale, name) {
  console.log(locale.helloText + ' ' + name)
}

// get the module asyncly
async function loadLocale(countryCode, thenDoThis, ...optionalArgs) => {
  const locale = await import(`flatpickr/dist/l10n/${countryCode}.js`)
  thenDoThis(locale, ...optionalArgs)
})

loadLocale('DE', sayHelloTo, 'John') // runs asyncly
```